# How I can set a notification which UserNotifications Framework

Tags: swift, swift3, calendar, ios10, uilocalnotification

I can set a notification in a time interval but I don't know how make it in a specific time and date, I try this but don't work

```
let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

func notificationSender(){

    center.requestAuthorization([.sound, .alert]) {
        (granted, error) in
        // We can register for remote notifications here too!
    }

    var date = DateComponents()
    date.hour = 13
    date.minute = 57

    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger.init(dateMatching: date , repeats: false)

    let content = UNNotificationContent()
    // edit your content

    let notification = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "myNotification", content: content, trigger: trigger)
```

center.add(notification)
    }

the notification need to be repeated every Monday and Friday at 3 pm

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there. Not much left for you to do.

What you are missing is as follow:

- You should add `weekday` to your date components, `1` is for Sunday so in your case you will need to set it to `2` for the Monday notification and `6` for your Friday notification
- If you need it to repeat you need to set the parameter `repeats` to `true` in your `UNCalendarNotificationTrigger`.

Here is a example.

```
// Create date components that will match each Monday at 15:00
var dateComponents = DateComponents()
dateComponents.hour = 15
dateComponents.minute = 0
dateComponents.weekday = 2 // Monday

// Create a calendar trigger for our date compontents that will repeat
let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents,
                                            repeats: true)

// Create the content for our notification
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
content.title = "Foobar"
content.body = "You will see this notification each monday at 15:00"

// Create the actual notification
let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "foo",
                                    content: content,
                                    trigger: trigger)

// Add our notification to the notification center
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request)
```