# UIDatePicker problems - not displaying time correctly

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

I want to save the time that the user picks from UIDatePicker into a core data entity of type String (I just picked String to fit the code below. Open for suggestions here). The intention is to use [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40060373) later on to send the user internal notifications at the time selected.

When the user selects **20:00** and hits the save button, **I want 20:00 to be displayed**. However instead, it displays :

```
<NSDateFormatter: 0x60000024f8a0>
```

in the rows of the table. Everytime a time is added, the output is like above, instead of the actual time being displayed. My aim is just to store the time so I can send them notifications like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40060373).

Here is the code of the button :

```
@IBAction func addBobBtnTapped(_ sender: AnyObject)
    {
        let context =  (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext //creates an object of a property in AppDelegate.swift so we can access it

        let bob = Bob(context: context)
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm"
        dateFormatter.string(from: timeSetbyUser.date)

        bob.timeToPing = dateFormatter.description
            //timeSetbyUser.date as NSDate?

        //Save the data to core data
        (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()
        navigationController!.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace the following two lines:

```
dateFormatter.string(from: timeSetbyUser.date)

bob.timeToPing = dateFormatter.description
```

with:

```
bob.timeToPing = dateFormatter.string(from: timeSetbyUser.date)
```

Do not ignore warnings. You should be seeing a warning on the line:

```
dateFormatter.string(from: timeSetbyUser.date)
```

about the return value being unused. That's an important clue.

You should also change the date format. Either use `HH:mm` for 24-hour time or use `hh:mm a` for 12-hour time with am/pm.

Comment: Works!! Thanks you very much for the pointer and the quick reply! I don't see any warnings. Am I missing something bro ?

Comment: Also, as you're an experienced dev, what is your advise on the above approach for implementing notifications at the time and day (to be coded) set by the user ? Thanks!