# How to push local notification every specific N days when minimize app iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, local

How can i push a local notification at specific time (ex: 9:00AM) in specific N day get from DB. I tried timer to add a Notification but it's seem like Timer is suppense when i minimize app. Here's my code:

```
func createTriggerLocalPushNotification(completion: @escaping(Error?) -> ()) {

    var date = Date()
    date.hour = 12
    date.minute = 0
    date.second = 0
    var timeInterval = 86400 * 3 // Default 3 day
    var timeBuffer:TimeInterval = 0
    guard let inActivePushString = RealmUserInfo.shared.getValue(with: keyInActiveTimePush),
        let inActivePushTime = Int(inActivePushString), inActivePushTime > 0 else {
        log.info("Can't trigger inActivePushTime")
            return
    }

    date.add(.day, value: inActivePushTime)

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        timeInterval = 86400 * inActivePushTime
        timeBuffer = date.timeIntervalSinceNow

        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.body = self.contentMessage
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
        content.categoryIdentifier = self.inActiveTimePushNotificationCategory

        // Buffer trigger when first time
        var dateComponents = DateComponents()
        dateComponents.day = Date().day + inActivePushTime
        dateComponents.hour = 12
        dateComponents.minute = 0
        let firstTrigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: false)
        let requestBuffer = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: self.bufferInActiveTimePushNotification, content: content, trigger: firstTrigger)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(requestBuffer, withCompletionHandler: nil)

        // Create content
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: timeBuffer, repeats: false) { (timer) in
            // Create trigger
            let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: TimeInterval(timeInterval), repeats: true)
            let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: self.inActiveTimePushNotification, content: content, trigger: trigger)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
            }
        completion(nil)
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
        let content = UILocalNotification()
        content.alertBody = contentMessage
        content.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
        content.category = inActiveTimePushNotification
        content.fireDate = date
        content.repeatInterval = .day
        UIApplication.shared.scheduleLocalNotification(content)
        completion(nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set Local push notification after 3 days with specific time like 10:00 PM, When user open application OR just enter the app in foreground every time we can get 
 `applicationDidBecomeActive` delegate method, In this method you need to remove old local push notification if exist and reset after 3 days with a specific time.

See this post to set local push notification with N days.
[Repeating local notifications for specific days of week (Swift 3 IOS 10)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45061324/repeating-local-notifications-for-specific-days-of-week-swift-3-ios-10)

Comment: In those articles, it look like we could get date components by weekday, day...etc, and that's not helping me. Currently i can set a notification in the next N day. But i don't know how to automatically reset it. Like this:


var dateComponents = DateComponents()
        dateComponents.day = Date().day + 3
        dateComponents.hour = 12
        dateComponents.minute = 0
        let firstTrigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: false)