# How to set alerts in UNNotificationCenter some days before?

Tags: ios, swift, usernotifications

How I can make local notification be triggered before some days? For example, I create local notifications from dateComponents:

```
    var dateComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.month, .day], from: birthDate)
    dateComponents.hour = 10
    dateComponents.minute = 30
    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: true)
```

I get days from:

```
var dateComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.month, .day], from: birthDate).
```

But how I can set them triggered before one day at specifiс time?

Comment: I recommend to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45061324/repeating-local-notifications-for-specific-days-of-week-swift-3-ios-10)

Comment: Thank you, but I haven't found a solution there. This thread only about triggering for specific days of week.

Comment: your question is not clear. Please specify which cases are understood as "before some days?" What kind of days?

Comment: I updated my question with this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if let oneDayAgo = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -1, to: birthDate) {
    var dateComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.month, .day], from: oneDayAgo)
    dateComponents.hour = 10
    dateComponents.minute = 30
    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: true)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for solution!